# Returning ajax data to different functions corresponding to different links

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I'm at peak-frustration trying to resolve my mental block re: callbacks. I've read [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) and [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) (among many other posts), and indeed the latter was helpful with another problem. However what I'm trying to do now is just slightly different and I'm losing my mind trying to adapt it to my code. Maybe my approach is entirely wrong/fundamentally flawed (and not just immature, which I can live with)?

The essence of my problem is that rather than simply returning ajax result to a callback function, I need the resulting json to be available to different functions, corresponding to different events, i.e.:

linkOne.onclick = invoke ajaxReq + getJsonData, then call functionOne with getJsonData result as an argument
linkTwo.onclick = invoke ajaxReq + getJsonData, then call functionTwo with getJsonData result as an argument
linkThree.onclick = invoke ajaxReq + getJsonData, then call functionThree with getJsonData result as an argument

Can't this be done with the link.onclick definition? Why doesn't this work:

```
linkThree.onclick = functionOne(getJsonData);
```

Here's my code:

```
function ajaxReq() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return request;
}

function getJsonData() {
    var request = ajaxReq();
    request.open("GET", "/myJSON.json", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var myJsonArray = myJsonString["An Array in myJSON.json"];
                // functionOne(myJsonArray); // callback: what if I need to pass this value to various functions?
                return myJsonArray; // ... 'cause this ain't doin' it, and I don't know why
            }
        }
    } // onreadystatechange
} // getJsonData

function functionOne(myJsonArray) {
    var myJsonArray = getJsonData(); // why doesn't this work, since, in getJsonData, var request = ajaxReq(); returns an ajax request ?
}
```

And why, if var request = ajaxReq(); invokes ajaxReq function and returns its result to getJsonData, does var myJsonArray = getJsonData(); in functionOne not do the same?

Any help with this is much appreciated. (p.s. seeking a pure javascript fix, not jQuery.)

svs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been answered in the links you have specified, that we cannot return value from asynchronous call to use it in a synchronous function call. So here is the trick -

Assign all the onclick listeners a common function.

```
link1.onclick = someCommonfunction;
link2.onclick = someCommonfunction;
link3.onclick = someCommonfunction;
```

And define the common function like following, which will have json data in the callback, and you can pass that data to any function call.

```
function someCommonfunction(e) {
    /* this is the function which will be finally executed with json data after clicking */
    var callback = function(jsonData) {
        var myJsonArray = jsonData; 
        //do some condition check and call functionOne, functionTwo or functionThree

    };  
    getJsonData(callback);    
}
```

I modified `getJsonData` to call `callback` with the response data.

```
function getJsonData(callback) {
    var request = ajaxReq();
    request.open("GET", "/myJSON.json", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var myJsonArray = myJsonString["An Array in myJSON.json"];              
                callback(myJsonArray);              
            }
        }
    } // onreadystatechange
} // getJsonData
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand this structure, tho maybe not 100%. Based on your answer, wouldn't it also be viable to simply check conditions where you have callback(myJsonArray), and instead, for each condition a unique callback, i.e., if (condition1){functionOne(myJsonArray); }, else if (condition2){functionTwo(myJsonArray); } ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes you can do that too.

Comment: Thanks again. I've been working on this and now I'm revisiting the concept. Since I would be unnecessarily reloading the same data, perhaps I should instead call the ajax/getJsonData onload, and then figure how to make this data avail to other functions, once the page has loaded. Cheers, svs